# How can i set a product buying corner image on footer which will be scrollable

Tags: html, css

I want to add a sticky image in my footer. I want to accomplish this using only html and css. Can anyone help me figure out how to do this?

here is the image - https://prnt.sc/whc1kq

also, here is my html and css code:

html- https://prnt.sc/whca7m

css- https://prnt.sc/whc528

thank you in advance

Comment: Please include the code snippets for the HTML/CSS in your question. It will speed up the process of providing you help.

Comment: I want to sticky a image on footer. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For aligning any image at bottom of the screen with sticky behaviour

```
.fixImage{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
}
<img src="yourimagepath" class="fixImage"/>
```

As per the requester query I have updated code with `max-width: 250px`

```css
    .fixImage{
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    max-width: 250px;
    }
```

```html
<img src="https://placehold.it/412x413" class="fixImage"/>
```

Comment: i want to resize it .. how can i? I set width: 200px but it won't perfectly.

Comment: What's the current dimension of your image. Use `max-width` instead of width to resize proportionally.

Comment: the dimension is 412*413 pixels but i want to it 250*250pixels. :3

Comment: Use `max-width: 250px` to resize proportionally.

Comment: after sizing `max-width: 250px` .. my image shows half..

Comment: Could you please add your code in your question. So that I can have a look at your issue

Comment: `.add-corner-image{
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
max-width: 250px;
}`

Comment: https://prnt.sc/wheyeq  here is the image after setting max-width

Comment: I have updated the answer and it is working fine with `max-width: 250px`. Please check

Comment: Thank you so much man.. It working now perfectly.. Thank you sooo much .

Comment: happy to help. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Try with position absolute instead of sticky and tweak with the margins. I m pretty sure this will work.

Comment: after setting  absolute it fixed on only footer.. it dont act scrollable

Comment: I meant on the image, my bad maybe I did not explain it properly. Try setting position:absolute on the .fixImage not on the footer. This should keep it 'scrollable' too since it will keep the certain margin you set wherever you scroll (similar to how sticky works but I think this overwrites some browser defaults that might make sticky not work all the time)

Comment: `i understand it and i set it into .fixImage but it acts as i said it before`

Comment: Try maybe with sticky too? Position sticky and then set some margins. There may be some defaults that wordpress adds and this messes up your styles.  Still the sollution is one of these: sticky, fixed or absolute.

Answer (score -1):

Do you mean like this?

```
position: absolute;
position: sticky;
z-index: 1;
float: right;
```